# SQL 2008 user defined function not recognized

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

This is my first attempt at a user defined function so I am having some issues identifying what I am doing incorrectly.  My goal is to create a function that will accept a part id as a paramater and then processes a series of if conditions that analyze the second character in the ID to determine product type based on standard naming conventions.  I have made a few tweaks in the script, I have ran each version in master as well as the database.  I have not received any failure errors when creating the function however each attempt at using it results in the following error.  'get_product_type' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Current version of this function is bellow.

```
create function get_product_type (@part nvarchar(30))
returns nvarchar(30)
with execute as caller
as 
begin
    DECLARE @product nvarchar(30);
    if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'A' 
        set @product = 'ELLIPTICAL';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'B' 
        set @product = 'F&D SPHERICAL';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'C' 
        set @product = 'F&D SPHERICAL';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'D' 
        set @product = 'HEMISPHERICAL';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'E' 
        set @product = 'CONICAL';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'F' 
        set @product = 'FLANGED ONLY';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'G' 
        set @product = 'DISHED ONLY';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'H' 
        set @product = 'TULIP BOWL';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'I' 
        set @product = 'TESTING/COUPONS/CHARPIES';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'J' 
        set @product = 'FLARED/DISHED';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'K' 
        set @product = 'HEAD BRACES';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'L' 
        set @product = 'MISCELLANEOUS';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'M' 
        set @product = 'HEAD PAD EXTENSIONS';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'N' 
        set @product = 'HEAD PADS';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'O' 
        set @product = 'MISCELLANEOUS';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'P' 
        set @product = 'HUBS';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'Q' 
        set @product = 'FLANGED/FLUED';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'R' 
        set @product = 'FLUED/PLATE';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'S' 
        set @product = 'SILL PAD';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'T' 
        set @product = 'TOOLING';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'U' 
        set @product = 'CYLENDAR REPAD';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'V' 
        set @product = 'ROLLING CANS';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'W' 
        set @product = 'HEAT TREAT';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'X' 
        set @product = 'SPHERE';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'Y' 
        set @product = 'BLASTING';
    else if SUBSTRING(@part,1,1) = 'Z' 
        set @product = 'MISCELLANEOUS';
    else set @product = 'MISCELLANEOUS';

    return @product
end
```

If the issue is in how I have been trying to call the function, all of my attempst have been,

```
get_product_type(cl.PART_ID),
```

If anyone can provide a push in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: To clarify, I have been trying to call it within a select statement, I just did not want to include the entire query but I will modify the post accordingly

Comment: I kind of see what your saying, I will do some resarch.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, I am deffiantly still missing something, I tried                                           
select * from get_product_type 'aa' thinking it would return 'ELLIPTICAL' but now the error i get is - Invalid object name 'get_product_type'.

Comment: Yes, you are missing `dbo.` preceding the function name as @MartinSmith pointed out twice.

Comment: I have tried that as well.  It hasnt made a difference

Comment: Beside how to call a function you really should not use a function to do this -- you should use a lookup table.  This is a database, it will work much better if you use a lookup table.

Comment: @Hogan, that probably is true, I was kind of looking for a project to learn a bit more about functions though.  I would like to figure this approach out but outside of test I will likley take your advice.

Comment: The two part name is dbo.get_product_type.  I have tried dragging and droping it directly into the query and it still shows as an invalid object name.  I am assuming the function needs to be created on the database instead of master, and i have tried both.  Is that assumption correct or should it be on master?

Comment: Yes, I have executed the query.  The exact query is "select * from dbo.get_product_type('aa')" and the exact message is "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.get_product_type'."

Comment: I think this was mentioned earlier but I am on SQL server 2008 still.  THere have been a few issues in the past where that ended up explaning a lot, not sure if tthis is one of those circumstances or not.

Comment: Oh - don't use `select * from dbo.get_product_type('aa')` use  `select dbo.get_product_type('aa')` - it is a scalar function not a table valued function

Comment: I can find the function at Server->Databases->TEST->Programmability->Functions->Scalar-valued Functions->dbo.get_product_types.  I have reran the query with "Use TEST Go".  I am signed in a sa though I have not speciffically tried to assign user access to the function.  I dont want to take any more of your time unless something suddenly seems obvious, I do appreciate the help here.  Thank you Martin

Comment: Holly crap, your awesome lol.  Thaks again

Comment: @Dru -- on more note.  SQL is not really about using user defined functions.  You can do it if you have to but it is always slow and probably means your design is fundamentally wrong.  But now you know how to do it the wrong way please actually do it the right way!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like this -- it is very slow and you can use SQL to make this process fast using a left join

First define a table with two columns, a one character code and a description

It would look something like this

```
 CREATE TABLE LOOKUP (
    CODE CHAR(1),
    DESC VARCHAR(100)
 )
```

Make the CODE field the primary key.

Then you can "call" your function like this:

```
 SELECT 
   COALESCE(LOOKUP.DESC,'MISCELLANEOUS') AS DESC
 FROM TABLENAMEHERE
 LEFT JOIN LOOKUP ON LOOKUP.CODE =  SUBSTRING(TABLENAMEHERE.PRODUCTCODE,1,1)
```